# How to use IN condition along with LEFT OUTER JOIN and ON

Tags: mysql

I want to use IN condition, it works with the value not work with the variable of another table, Here is my sample

```
SELECT  A.*,B.* 
FROM table1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN erp_wh_salhd AS B ON B.InvNo = '15'  AND A.InvNo IN (B.filter1) 
//Not working  Comming only one row for B table
```

if I pass values directly means it works, i.e

```
SELECT  A.*,B.* 
FROM table1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN erp_wh_salhd AS B ON B.InvNo = '15'  AND A.InvNo IN (2,3)  
// Working. table B have two values
```

Comment: Are you storing CSV data in the `filter1` column?  Please add some sample data from both tables.

Comment: no with two tables

Comment: Please add tables and expected result

Comment: You should fix your schema design. Filter should be rows in a separate table

Comment: Please edit your question to explain why you think the first should work. Because otherwise we can't expalin why your expectations are wrong. Read the manual re IN: 1. IN with a list as a function & IN with a subquery as "= ANY". Also why do you need us to tell you? What don't you understand in the manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `filter1` field in `erp_wh_salhd` is a comma separated list of values, you will need to use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT  A.*,B.* 
FROM table1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN erp_wh_salhd AS B ON B.InvNo = '15'  AND FIND_IN_SET(A.InvNo, B.filter1)
```

Comment: if we have only one value for filter1 means it returns value for both row

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you show some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Do the fact you are using join  you could try using =

```
    SELECT  A.*,B.* 
    FROM table1 AS A 
    LEFT JOIN erp_wh_salhd AS B ON B.InvNo = '15'  
        AND A.InvNo  = B.filter1
```

Answer (score 0):

The IN clause allows for multiple values. In your first query you only provide one value, however:

```
AND A.InvNo IN (B.filter1)
```

That is equal to

```
AND A.InvNo = B.filter1
```

So you only join those B rows to an A row where the B row's InvNo is 15 and its filter1 equals A's InvNo.

In your second query you join all B rows whose InvNo is 15 to all A rows whose InvNo is either 2 or 3.

Two completely different queries, you cannot really compare.